# Oracle Cloud: How to fill json file for custom metrics

Tags: metrics, oracle-cloud-infrastructure, telemetry

I am trying to send custom t2 telemetry metrics to Oracle Cloud. Using below Command I am able to generate param json file.

```
oci monitoring metric-data post --generate-param-json-input metric-data > metric-data.json
```

Below is the generate metric-data.json file

```
[
  {
    "compartmentId": "string",
    "datapoints": [
      {
        "count": 0,
        "timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      {
        "count": 0,
        "timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "dimensions": {
      "string1": "string",
      "string2": "string"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "string1": "string",
      "string2": "string"
    },
    "name": "string",
    "namespace": "string",
    "resourceGroup": "string"
  },
  {
    "compartmentId": "string",
    "datapoints": [
      {
        "count": 0,
        "timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "value": 0.0
      },
      {
        "count": 0,
        "timestamp": "2017-01-01T00:00:00+00:00",
        "value": 0.0
      }
    ],
    "dimensions": {
      "string1": "string",
      "string2": "string"
    },
    "metadata": {
      "string1": "string",
      "string2": "string"
    },
    "name": "string",
    "namespace": "string",
    "resourceGroup": "string"
  }
]
```

My metrics requirement is below. Need to send below information in case any agent id is late or missing.

```
MetricsName: [late/missing]
Hostname: somexyz.oraclecloud.com
agentid: asdfkjgsjdg723
category: custom/DB/Webserver
Region: 
AD:
Information1:
Information2:
```

So my question is below.

1. How to accomodate my information in metric-data.json file
2. On Cloud how to visualise my data
3. Do I need to register my service on cloud before sending it

Answer (score 0):

On Cloud how to visualise my data

> Use Metrics Explorer in OCI Console

Do I need to register my service on cloud before sending it

> No need to register

Sample data -

```
[
   {
      "namespace":"monitoring",
      "compartmentId":"$compartmentID",
      "resourceGroup":"gpu_0_monitoring",
      "name":"gpuTemperature",
      "dimensions":{
         "resourceId":"$instanceOCID",
         "instanceName":"$instanceName"
      },
      "metadata":{
         "unit":"degrees Celcius",
         "displayName":"GPU Temperature"
      },
      "datapoints":[
         {
            "timestamp":"2022-12-06T12:43:40Z",
            "value":43
         }
      ]
   }
]
```

Save this data in metric-data.json file.

The above is a sample data that you posting to the monitoring service.

oci monitoring metric-data post --metric-data file://metric-data.json

For visualisation you can refer to the below document.
https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/Monitoring/Tasks/publishingcustommetrics.htm